# The method "X" is undefined for the type

Tags: java, rest, junit, mocking

I am trying to use `wiremock 1.46` with `junit-4.11` and i am following the examples on the [wiremock website](http://wiremock.org/getting-started.html) and when i try to use the following piece of code

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/my/resource"))
                .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("text/xml"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                    .withBody("<response>Some content</response>")));
```

i am getting the following errors

```
the method aResponse() is undefiened for the type
the method equalTo() is undefiened for the type
the method urlEqualTo() is undefiened for the type
```

i am guessing that this is happening because i need another JAR file for these but does anyone know what JAR files are needed for these methods?

Comment: the type is the test itself (e.g. SettlementStructureTest.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you just forgot

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
```

The methods you are trying to invoke are `static` methods of the `WireMock` type. They aren't `static` methods of your custom type. You either `import` as above, or invoke them with the qualified name of the type.

Comment: you are correct, that solved it :) i added this first then must have saved the file as this removed it before i added the method so it removed the unused import without me knowing. presumed it was there from when i added it at the start